# easy exercise with difficult solution C++

Tags: c++, digits, logarithm

So, first of all, this SEEMS like one of those exercises that you receive in school when you first start studying programming. Weeeeell it proves to be more than that.

The main exercise is fairly simple, solvable by anyone:

Edit: I got a hold of the original (translated) statement:

Write two implementations for a function that's nonrecursive which has one argument (n = a natural number with 9 digits at most) that returns the number you get by repositioning the first digit of n to the end of the number. As an example, if n is 4273, the function should return 2734.
C1) You're allowed to use loops.
C2) You're not allowed to use loops.

Aight, first's easy.

```
    long function(long n)
    {
        long newNumber = 0, p = 1;

        while(n>9)
        {
            newNumber = n%10 * p + newNumber;
            n = n/10;
            p = p*10;
        }

        return newNumber*10+n;
    }
```

NOW do the same thing without using any kind of loops. No while, for, do while, etc. You don't know how long the number is, might be 3 digits, might me 9. Also the whole work must be done by one function alone.

Now, of course, one simple solution, and a hideous one would be to write something like

```
    if(n<100)
        return n%10*10+n/10;
    else
        if(n<1000)
            return n%100*10+n/100;
        else
            if...
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

but that's not the most desirable piece of code. Is there any other clean way of doing this? So far nobody I've asked knew of any other way.

There's another thing. This is supposed to be solvable by a beginner (I came across this while helping a buddy of mine solve one of his exercises) so using some fancy libraries that somehow help that a beginner would never know about shouldn't be a valid solution (yet I'm curious about all the ideas).

Also, I know that you can find out the number of digits a number has by using the formula:

|log(n)| + 1 = ln(n) / ln(10) + 1 which could be used in C++ as follows:

```
    long function(long n)
    {
            int k; // number of digits of n

            k = (int) (ln(n) / ln(10)) + 1; // applying the formula
            long p = pow(10, k-1);
            return n%p * 10 + n/p;
    }
```

But I don't remember ever being taught about ln functions in C++ while I was in high school and neither were they. So... Is there any other beginner friendly way of doing this?

List of constraints:

- one single function
- no loops
- receives only 1 parameter in the form of a number (of at most 9 digits)
- returns the number formed by repositioning its first digit to the end of the number
- no strings (even though that's a legit solution)

Edit: So in the meanwhile i've been told that the solution the ones that proposed this problem was the one using logarithms..... Which is weird, because their students never used that in c++. My guess is that they fucked up with the statement and that's their "salvation excuse".

Comment: Have you even considered to use recursive function?

Comment: Can you call any standard library function?

Comment: Do you have to use a number? This is trivial with a string.

Comment: Does your exercise dictate that you have to C++, and that the prototype of the function to implement is `long function(long)`?

Comment: you can always convert to a string anyway

Comment: I imagine this can be done in a number of ways, but keep in mind that i'm wondering if there is a BEGINNER friendly solution that the guy that received this could implement. You can convert it to a string, but they haven't even learned of strings. (...yep :D) I mentioned recursive functions. Might show me what you got in mind? (ONE single recursive function that receives a number as a parameter and returns the number that has its first digit positioned at the end). I'm looking for the simplest method you can think of, yet yes, I personally am curious about any other ideas as well.

Comment: @GabrielEm Solutions don't tend to be dependent on if the asker is a BEGINNER, PEBCAK or EXPERT. Solutions ar solutions.

Comment: I agree with that, yet since he got that exercise without knowing much of anything, it implies that there should be a solution that he is able to implement. That's what's bugging me. Right now i'm wondering about Lee's recursive function.

Comment: I am always annoyed when stuff like recursion is covered before std::string.

Comment: Converting to a string involves a loop.  Recursion is essenrially a while loop, because there has to be the test to stop recursion.

Comment: I'll give you that all sorts of fun loopishness is going on inside `std::string`, but the same can be said for just about everything `ln` and `pow`-ish. To discard all looping, you can recurse mod and div. Or you can recurse and move digits around. The end result will be the same.

Comment: The rules have been firmed up and this now illustrates a different concept. Add enough constraints and even the simplest of problems can become difficult. This is a good exercise to remember should you ever find yourself writing code for safety critical systems.

Comment: It always seem funny to me when someone says "We weren't thought how to use math in programming."

Comment: @jure well it's not about not being taught how to use math. In fact I'm 100% positive that he knows all about that logarithmic formula (or should have known). It's just that such functions aren't usually something students come across during their early computer science classes, thus nobody found the solution. I agree that a diligent student could have found out about the formula, and then look after "how to use logarithms in c++" tho.

Comment: No loops though. You have any idea how many loops are in that logarithm computation? And why screw around with ln/ln when there is a perfectly usable [`std::log10`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log10)? And don't get me started on the weird results you can get from truncating the floating point values returned from `pow `

Comment: Yeah, I'm overthinking this. `log` and `pow` are easy to read and understand, even if they are "horrible" practical solutions. `pow`s of ten should work up to 9 decimal places, but I have seen mingw's ports of GCC 4.8 and 4.9 crap out 99 for `std::pow(10, 2);`. Not fun watching new programmers freaking out over that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one solution that uses std::log10 and std::pow (requires `#include <cmath>`).

```
long func(long in) {
    long base = std::pow(10, (int)std::log10(in));
    long left_most_num = in / base;
    long body = in - left_most_num * base;
    return body * 10 + left_most_num;
}
```

Comment: This one is the closest to what was expected from that statement (so I've heard), so I'm marking this as the accepted solution, even though there are a lot of creative solutions that follow the constraints more or less in this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Use [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion). Here is some untested code:

```
long f(long n, long base) 
{
    if(n <= 9)
        return n;    // last 'iteration'
    else
        return (base * (n % 10)) + f(n / 10, 10 * base);
}

....
f(1234, 10);
```

Comment: At this point, the function no longer has the same number of arguments as given by the OP so it's questionable whether this counts as a solution.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe - good point, but easily fixed - wrap it with an external function with just one variable.

Comment: Note that the OP wrote 'The whole work must be done by one function alone.'

Comment: You are right. Well, it is ONE function. Where did you see anything about the number of arguments?

Comment: Yep, this was correct in fact. It works. Indeed there was nothing mentioned about the number of arguments, tho it should have... My bad. Still, this works.

Comment: An ugly correction to lower the number of arguments could be to make `base` a static variable, like [here](https://ideone.com/p4zPOj).

Comment: I actually never thought of this @Bob__ . Even though it's 'kind of cheating' I still like the idea. Of course they weren't taught about static variables but still.

Comment: This function is not tail recursive. Tail recursive function must have a recursive call as its last "action" performed. And your function has an extra addition after recursive call. Could be solved with extra accumulator parameter, though.

Comment: @GabrielEm great time to learn. Any instructor who penalizes a student for reading ahead should be drummed out of the profession.

Answer (score 1):

If you were allowed to use strings, you would be able to do something like this.  It uses a string to basically treat the number as a vector, making this task trivial.

As it stands now, though, this is unallowed (as of edit #3 to the question, which I didn't see while writing & testing this solution).  However, I'll post it here in case anyone is directed to this question in the future, and isn't limited to not using strings.

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

long firstDigitToEnd(long n) {
    bool neg = (n < 0);                  // Preserve signed-ness.
    if (neg) { n = labs(n); }            // Obtain absolute value, for convenience.

    std::string num = std::to_string(n); // Convert number to string.

    char first = num[0];                 // Obtain first digit.
    num.erase(0, 1);                     // Erase first digit, shift rest forwards.
    num.push_back(first);                // Append first digit to end.

    // And we're done.  Convert string back to number, restore signed-ness.
    return (neg ? -(std::stol(num)) : std::stol(num));
}

// -----

// Testing code.

#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

void readCin(long& l);

int main() {
    long n = 0;

    do {
        if (n) {
            std::cout << "Result: " << firstDigitToEnd(n) << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << "Input number, or 0 to exit: ";
        readCin(n);
    } while (n);

    std::cout << "...And we're gone." << std::endl;
}

// Read a number, or clear the buffer if non-number is entered.
void readCin(long& l) {
    using std::cin;

    cin >> l;
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    if (cin.fail()) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        l = 0;
    }
}
```

See it in action [here](http://ideone.com/8oWH2o).

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 1**: Changed to not use loops.
**Edit 2**: This solution no longer satisfies the requirements the OP has set. However, I will leave my answer here for future readers with this problem that may be able to use strings in their solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    long testNum = 0;
    long newNum;
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    std::cin >> testNum;

    std::string stringFromLong;

    stringFromLong = std::to_string(testNum);
    char tempChar = stringFromLong[0];

    std::string newString = stringFromLong.substr(1, stringFromLong.length() - 1) + tempChar;

    newNum = std::stol(newString);
    std::cout << newNum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This will take in a number and convert it to a string. It will them hold the first character of the string in a temp variable. A new string is made from our original string (starting at the second character and going to the last character) plus our temp character put at the end. It then uses `std::stol()` to convert our string to a long for output.

Comment: If all you are going to do is `cin` and `cout` the number, why bother with the number at all? Just stay string the whole way. That said, how do you know the contents of the string is a number? But you have that problem anyway. Recommend an `if (std::cin >> testNum)` to prevent the undefined behaviour of using unchecked input.

Comment: I use `cin` and `cout` to get input as a `long` and output a `long` because that was the requirement.

Comment: "function that takes a number (9 digits long at most)" the storage format and representation of that number was not defined. A poorly written requirements document can cost a lot of money in the real world.

Comment: @user4581301: Yes. I made the assumption it was a requirement because that's what the OP was using.

Comment: OP just clarified the rules. String is now completely off the table. Strings get no love in CompSci.

Answer (score 0):

With the constraint that we know INT_MAX at compile time, it's trivial, if ugly.

```
if(x > 999999999)
   ndigits =  9;
else if(x > 99999999)
   ndigits = 8;
```

etc;
Then you can use ndigits and multiplication. division and modulus the associated powers of ten to get the result you want.

However if x is unbounded then there is inherently no way of knowing its magnitude without using some form of loop.